# List all databases accessed by integration on the Notion

Tags: api, notion-api

Is there a more efficient way to get the list of all databases in notion? I have tried using the `https://api.notion.com/v1/databases` endpoint but it's deprecated now. Another option is the `/search` endpoint but it is returning all the records within the database as well.

Can someone provide a better way to list all databases which are accessed by an integration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to filter for databases in the `/search` endpoint to only get databases back. In Python your payload would look like this:

```
payload = {
    'filter': {
        'value': 'database',
        'property': 'object'
    }
}
```